# TextViews getting repositioned after calling setText(). Is this a bug?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-loader

I'm experiencing the weirdest problem I've ever seen. I have a basic two-pane view. There's a pane that lists medications, and clicking a medication brings up the second pane, which contains the details about that medication. The details fragment is supposed to be arranged like this:

```
[Med Name]
[Med Dosage]
[Date Filled]
[Duration]
```

And the XML code bears this out, as far as I can tell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dosageDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="dosage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateFilledDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dosageDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/durationDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateFilledDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="duration"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I set the strings to be displayed by each field using this code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor mCursor) {
    int count = mCursor.getCount();
    String str = "There are " + count + " rows.";
    // TODO: REMOVE THIS TOAST
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int nameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MedTable.MED_NAME);
    int dosageIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MedTable.MED_DOSAGE);
    int dateIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MedTable.MED_DATE_FILLED);
    int durationIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MedTable.MED_DURATION);
    if(mCursor != null) {
        // Moves to the next row in the cursor.
        while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Create the name string
            String medName = "Name: " + mCursor.getString(nameIndex);

            // Create the dosage string
            String medDosage = "Dosage: " + mCursor.getString(dosageIndex);

            // Create a date format to parse the date string
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String epochString = mCursor.getString(dateIndex);
            long epoch = Long.parseLong(epochString);
            String date = sdf.format(new Date(epoch * 1000));

            // Create the date string
            String medDate = "Date Filled: " + date;

            // Create the duration string
            String medDuration = "Duration: " + mCursor.getString(durationIndex) + " days";

            // Setting the name
            TextView nameView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nameDetailsView);
            nameView.setText(medName);

            // Setting dosage
            TextView dosageView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dosageDetailsView);
            dosageView.setText(medDosage);

            // Setting the date
            TextView dateView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dateFilledDetailsView);
            dateView.setText(medDate);

            // Setting the duration
            TextView durationView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.durationDetailsView);
            durationView.setText(medDuration);
            // end of while loop
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the program, the weirdest thing happens. Namely, the TextViews get reordered somehow.
Instead of the desired order, I somehow get

```
[Date Filled]
[Dosage]
[Name]
[Duration]
```

Can anyone tell me why on earth this might be happening?

EDIT: Commenting out the various calls to setText() causes the TextViews to display in the correct order, albeit with the hardcoded text, instead of what I want.

EDIT AGAIN: Turns out all I needed to do was clean the project. Now I know.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. It could be that R.java has become corrupt.

Comment: Good call. I feel like a dope now.

Comment: Glad to help. I always clean my projects if I see something screwy with resources. It seems the resource ids in R.java had somehow got swapped for your nameDetailsView and your dateFilledDetailsView. Depending on how you edit things and the tools you use to do it, it can happen from time to time.

Comment: do one thing 1st check whether the medName,medDosage,dateFilled and  medDuration string variable are  having expected values or not .Do  println.

Comment: Can you try and use Linear Layout ? and check with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try and remove `+` sign from all `android:layout_below` tags and make it like: 
 `android:layout_below="@id/dateFilledDetailsView"`. The `+` sign in the id declaration should be used only on the first appearance of the id. So have something as follows and comment the result:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dosageDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nameDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="dosage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateFilledDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dosageDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/durationDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dateFilledDetailsView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="duration"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**:

For the sake keeping the answer updated, @Squonk's comment worked perfectly. The real issue was that R.java got corrupt. Cleaning the project solved the problem.

Comment: Nothing has changed. The order is still the same. Thanks for the prompt response though. Any other ideas?
EDIT: Commenting out the various calls for setText() causes the TextViews to display in the correct order, albeit with the default text instead of what I want. This leads me to believe it's related to that.

Comment: Sidenote: Because I lack the patience to wait another 6 hours to answer my own question, I'm just going to accept this one, because it was the first one posted. Also because it taught me something new, namely that I only use the + for the initial ID assignment.

Comment: okay. Great to hear that your problem was solved. Although you might come to the question later or I can also edit the answer stating that finally cleaning your project as suggested by @Squonk's comment solved your problem.

Comment: Sure. That would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should find view in Fragment like this:

```
TextView nameView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nameDetailsView);
```

Why don't you inflate layout file in onCreateView method in Fragment, then find view by inflated layout view.

Comment: Is that something I can do? I initialize the loader in onCreateView, before I return the inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_med_detail, container, false). Also, I have to set the dynamic text in onLoadFinished. So how do I get the TextViews in that function?

Comment: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_med_detail, container, false);    mNameView = view.findViewById(R.id.nameDetailsView);` then set mNameView in onLoadedFinished